# ionic Background data download process

Tags: sqlite, ionic4

good companions
I am making an application that has SQLite and I have a problem.
I am trying to generate a service that downloads the information while the application is being used, but when it starts to download the lines and enter them in SQLite the application stops working, and when it finishes it comes back to itself.
I have checked that my calls do not have await and none do and it still behaves like this, does anyone have an idea of ​​what could be happening?
The first photo attached is the method that makes the download of articles.
And
I call it this way `this.dataSyncService.descargaArticulos(usuario.session_id);`
inside the async `ionViewWillEnter()`

[image: codigo]

Comment: Please post your code directly to the question, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, the next time I will do it as you comment. But can you help me with the problem I have?